# Find row by key made of String list

Tags: vb.net, linq

How can I find a row in a `DataGridView` using a key made of String list?
I compare cell values with another grid that has the same columns...

```
Private key As New List(Of String)
Dim rowFromAnotherGrid As DataGridViewRow
```

...

```
Me.key = New List(Of String) From {"Key1", "Key2"}
Dim row As DataGridViewRow

'This is obviously wrong - Expression does not produce a value:
row = (From r In Me.grid.Rows
       Where Me.key.ForEach(Function(subkey)
         Return r.Cells(subkey).Value = rowFromAnotherGrid.Cells(subkey).Value
       End Function)).FirstOrDefault
```

Something like that or maybe there's a better approach?

Comment: `keys.Any(Function(x) r.Cells(subkey).Value = x)`

Comment: Probably the easiest thing to do would be to write a `ListEquals` function (or whatever you prefer to name it) and use that to write your `Where` predicate.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did it like this, still believe in prettier solution:

```
'put searching key values in a list of string
Dim keyValuesToFind As List(Of String) = (From c As DataGridViewCell In rowFromAnotherGrid .Cells
                                                  From subkey In Me.key
                                                  Where c.OwningColumn.Name = subkey
                                                  Select CStr(c.Value)).ToList
```

...

```
Dim rowToFind As DataGridViewRow

'do the same for the grid in which we're searching and compare the lists
    rowToFind = Me.grid.Rows.Where(Function(r)
                                       Dim rowKey = (From c As DataGridViewCell In r.Cells
                                                     From subkey In Me.key
                                                     Where c.ColumnInfo.Name = subkey
                                                     Select CStr(c.Value)).ToList
                                       Dim ret = rowKey.Except(keyValuesToFind).Count = 0
                                       Return ret
                                   End Function).FirstOrDefault
```